# How to make an Excel nested if, else, and statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have this table:

If: columnD is "b" I want column E to return "Correct"

How do I do this?

Comment: your edits leave the question (and answers that were provided) somewhat pointless. I would suggest returning the original question or explaining why the answers provided weren't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(D1="B", "Correct",
IF(AND(A1="b", B1="b", C1="w"), "One",
IF(AND(A1="b", B1="w", C1="b"), "Two",
IF(AND(A1="b", B1="w", C1="w"), "Three"))))
```

Note if none of these conditions are met, it will return FALSE.

[image]

Comment: Well it will return `FALSE`, not an error.

Comment: @john232 - drag the formula down column E?

Comment: You are likely copying the syntax incorrectly. See my edit that shows it working. As BigBen said, you need to drag down the formula to all the cells in the range (the bottom right corner of the cell, see https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/01/20/copy-formula-excel/) for the formula to apply to the whole range.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in Excel 2019 or Excel 365 it's even easier.
IFS is basically a nested IF. It will return first TRUE result.

*=IFS([Something is True1, Value if True1,Something is True2,Value if True2,Something is True3,Value if True3)*

Write a formula (I formatted it for readability) in E1 and drag down (it will automatically change cell references):

```
=IFS(D1="b", "Correct", 
     AND(A1="b", B1="b", C1="w"), "One",
     AND(A1="b", B1="w", C1="b"), "Two",
     AND(A1="b", B1="w", C1="w"), "Three")
```

If you want to handle a situation that none of conditions are met (i.e. "last else") you can use this workaround:

```
=IFS(D1="b", "Correct", 
     AND(A1="b", B1="b", C1="w"), "One",
     AND(A1="b", B1="w", C1="b"), "Two",
     AND(A1="b", B1="w", C1="w"), "Three"
     TRUE, "Incorrect")
```

Comment: @john232 Are you using the same table as in example? Also make sure that you don't have spaces in the end.  

Click on the formula with Incorrect result and Evaluate it ("Formulas" ribbon tab -> "Formulas auditing" group -> "Evaluate Formula". Go step by step to see why it fails.